# Finding document/field length in Lucene 4

Tags: apache, lucene

I'm looking to have the ability to access the length (in terms) of a specific field of a document post-indexing. Preferably, if there is a way without re-indexing I would like to do that. But if re-indexing in a certain way will give easy access to this value, that would also serve.

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/03/new-index-statistics-in-lucene-40.html

That link (scoll down a bit and find the mention of *length*) talks of accessing the value at indexing time. I wish to be able to do so post-indexing. The link also talks about saving away the value to a doc value, but it gives no examples of how to do so.

If anyone could provide examples of saving the document length, or accessing it post-indexing, it would be incredibly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention of that statistic in the article is in reference to a [FieldInvertState](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInvertState.html).  Once you have that, it should be fairly straightforward how to get the statistics you are looking for (Just call `getLength`, `getUniquetermCount` or whatever you need).

The FieldInvertState is passed into the `Similarity`, particularly to the call [`Similarity.computeNorm`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html#computeNorm%28org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState,%20org.apache.lucene.index.Norm%29).  The norm value is calculated and stored at index time, rather than evaluated at query time, so making effective use of it would require you to reindex.

The typical way to make use of this would be to create a custom `Similarity`, possibly extending [`DefaultSimilarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html).  Simply overriding the `lengthNorm` method of `DefaultSimilarity` would be the simplest approach.  It's standard implementation is:

```
return (float)(1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms));
```

Which you could override with whatever you like.

That would work to tweak scoring based on a custom length-based calculation.  If that's not what you are looking for, but rather need to be able to just fetch that information, I would think just storing and the field, and getting the length from the field value returned when you fetch a `Document` would be the simplest implementation.

Comment: I understand the ability to override lengthNorm by extending DefaultSimilarity, making it return the length, but the lengthNorm method takes a FieldInvertState as a parameter. No methods in the Lucene 4 API return a FieldInvertState object. How am I suppose to use lengthNorm?

Thanks.

Comment: You set your custom Similarity class as the Similarity to be used when indexing and searching (IndexwriterConfig.setSimilarity and IndexSearcher.setSimilarity, respectively), and Lucene will make calls to it, passing a FieldInvertState to the computeNorm method whenever a document is indexed.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using IndexSearcher, I'm ranking the documents outside of the Lucene API with some basic code. It seems a bit excessive just for the length value, but I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @user2282763 I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  If you trying to rank the documents outside of the Lucene API, why use the Lucene API to do it?  Why not just get the length using String operations or some such?

Comment: I'm only using Lucene to traverse the indices.

Comment: It looks like my only option is to somehow obtain the length at indexing time and store it in a field. I'm confused as how to do even that.

Comment: I suppose you could pass a reader on the field content to your Analyzer, through `Analyzer.tokenStream`, then loop through the tokens with `TokenStream.nextToken()`, counting as you go.  Make sure and call `reset()` before the first call to `nextToken()`.  To be honest, though, this does feel a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Still, do what you will with it.

Comment: My apologies about the XY problem. I know it pretty much is one, but counting the tokens at indexing time seems to be good enough at the moment. Thanks.